# White streaks (image retention) on the sides of iPhone 5S screen?

Tags: screen, display, iphone

Not sure why this happened, but I had a conversation for 50 minutes and then realised some weird white streaks on the screen after I hung up. The streaks are now **gone** (gladly), it seems like the screen was overheating or something ??

What is the cause of this anomaly ?

**EDIT**

This seems to happen every time I make a phone call ! The white streaks appear and start fading over time. Am I the only one with this problem ?

**EDIT 2 **

Still have this problem but no permanent marks as of now. It's just a weird phenomenon that happens every time I receive a call.

---

Example of this (recreation) :

[image]

Comment: Try this image retention test: http://www.marco.org/rmbp-irtest.html

Comment: @Flavin What is that supposed to do ?

Comment: It is a test for image retention. You leave the checkerboard pattern up for some time, then flip to gray. If your screen has image retention problems, there will be a remnant of the checkerboard pattern visible on the gray screen. (Make sure you don't stare at the checkerboard, though, because your eyes certainly have an image retention problem.)

Comment: @Flavin Thank you but I already know I have the problem, as described by the problem above.